# Athenticate multiple users from my code to upload data to their own dropbox a/c using JavaScript Api

Tags: javascript, html, webforms, dropbox-api

How can I authenticate a multiple user from my code To Upload the file to their drop box Account with drop box java script API. Below is my code Which is working fine for single user,as I am first creating the "App-Key" in App Console for user's drop box account and then use this "App-Key" to authenticate the user.I have used the file uploader in HTML page.The Code is:-

```
var client = new Dropbox.Client({ key: 'App-Key' });

client.authenticate({ interactive: false }, function (error) {
        if (error) {
            alert('Error: ' + error);
        } else {
            SaveToDropbox();
        }
    });
 function SaveToDropbox() {
var file = document.getElementById('fileupload').files[0]
        var name = $('#fileupload').val();
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var data = e.target.result;

            client.writeFile(name , data, function (error, stat) {

                if (error) {
                    alert('Error: ' + error);
                } else {
                    alert('File Uploaded successfully!');
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

Please Help me what should I do If I want the multiple user will upload the files to their own drop box account from my project where I have implemented this javascript API code. How can I Get the "App-Key" for all the user who want to upload the data to their account. Can I ask the users to first create the app for developer in their a/c and provide the "App-Key" so that I can authenticate the user and upload the data to his account.I am using the datastore API not the Saver drop-ins API.

Answer (score 0):

This code looks okay at first glance and should work fine for all users. What's the problem you're running into? You don't need a separate app key for each user... your app should have a single app key.

Comment: This is working fine for single user's drop box account where i have created the app under this account,But my requirement is,I have running project in MVC where i want all the user of my project can upload the audio/video into their drop box account rather than server.

Comment: So what can i do in that case.Can i have to create separate app for each drop box account.Should i ask for every drop box member to first create app in developer and provide the app-key to integrate with their drop box account.Without creating app in user developer drop box a/c can i connect with their a/c.

Comment: Are you the same Ajay from the thread we had on the Dropbox forum? https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=109616 As I said there, you only need one app key, not one per user. Please make sure you've clicked "enable additional users" in the app console. Since you mentioned "where I have created the app under this account," I'm guessing you haven't, so you're seeing an error when you try to authorize in with a different account? If that's not it, please tell me the actual problem you're encountering (error message, if you're seeing one).